# Fatal - Eucalyptus installation failed

Tags: error-handling, installation, failed-installation, eucalyptus

When I install Eucalyptus cloud using the faststart method, I see that installation failed. When I check the log file later, I encounter the following errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is:

> Invalid gateway due to subnet/netmask for subnet...

Which means that the gateway value you entered is not in the subnet that you specified.

For example if you entered:

```
subnet: 10.111.0.0
netmask: 255.255.0.0
```

Then the gateway could be '10.111.0.1' but could not be '192.168.0.1' as that is not within the subnet.

Comment: Hi Mr. Steve, thank you very much for answer, 
it is for the network configuration of my VM:                                                                           
DEVICE="ens192"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="192.168.140.100"
PREFIX="24"
GATEWAY="192.168.128.200"
DNS1="192.168.128.12"
DNS2="192.168.63.12"
DNS3="8.8.8.8"
DNS4="8.8.4.4"